# Dronekit python goto_position_target_local_ned()

Tags: python, dronekit

Running dronekit-python with ArduCopter as SITL was successful.(APM:Copter V3.4-dev)

Then,I run the same code on the real copter(APM:Copter V3.2.1) is not work.
The code is from dronekit's example.
Any ideas or pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try flying with APM:Copter 3.3